# he sat him "on" or "at" his right hand

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> He called his son to the meeting room from the downstairs office. He sat him ***on /at*** his right hand.

Which one is correct, and if they both are, which would be more appropriate for a rather formal context.

Also, do I need to add ***side*** after *right hand*?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the *on* version doesn't really work at all, and the *at* version sounds too religious and/or formal. To be seated *at the right hand of God* is often said of Jesus Christ---he takes the place of honour next to the so-called Heavenly Father---and this is where most people will have heard the phrase.

Possibilities, from more to less formal:

- He seated his son at his right-hand side
- He seated his son on/to his right-hand side
- He seated his son to his right
- He seated his son on his right
- He sat his son to his right
- He sat his son on his right

If you wanted to be deliberately archaizing or over-formal, you could say

- He bade his son sit to his right
- He bade his son be seated to his right

Comment: In fact my real sentence **IS** from a religious text, you are incredible! I just wasn't sure if I can put a religious context on this site... Your answer gave me the idea to search in my KJV Bible (the one I use for translation of religious texts), and I found out that ON is the prefered preposition. Only twice AT is used but with the verb "SET DOWN" (not stand or sit or be seated) which I found peculiar.

Comment: Aha, that is interesting! I should make clear that what I said about 'on' being unacceptable is just my judgement of Present-Day English. It may well have been acceptable when the KJV was written. The same goes for 'set down'.

Comment: My former comment was not a criticism to your answer, but an apology for the "deceiving" way in which I asked my question. Will I be obsolete if in a religious text I use a set phrase from the KJV Bible then?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so at all. The influence of the KJV's phrasing is still everywhere to be found in literature. I don't think it will go away any time soon. Just be aware that it will evoke a specific set of associations in the reader---which, for your case, sound appropriate. Which language are you translating from?

Comment: Greek :) So sad StackExchange doesn't have a site for this language :(

Comment: Oh OK, cool. Yes, I think there should be one Stack Exchange for classical languages at least, to include Latin, Greek, Sanskrit, Hebrew, Arabic...but I don't think they're really making new sites. There is that new SE alternative that those Monica people founded. Maybe they'd be open to it. (Not suggesting Classical Greek and Modern Greek are the same, btw.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would be open to both, though my knowledge of Ancient Greek is 10% of my Modern Greek.

Comment: "On his right hand" is one of those expressions from the KJV which sound a little odd to modern ears. To me, it conjures up visions of one person literally sitting _on_ another's hand. But, as @legatrix says, many phrases from the KJV have passed into general use (at least among the older generation).

Comment: I agree that nowadays it sounds like literally sitting on another's hand.

Comment: I hope the readers of this book I am translating will recognise these set phrases from the KJV without being confused. Especially if I give the biblical reference.

Comment: Yeah. I think a good rule of thumb would be: If you have to spell out the reference, don't use the phrasing. (That would be μαργαρίτας τοις κυσίν, to stay Biblical!)